# type error with CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt

Tags: printf, ocaml

I am writing loop by recursion and I have problem:

```
let isRectangleIn a b c d =
  if (a > c && b > d) || (a>d && b>c) 
    then 
      "TAK"
    else
      "NIE";;

let rec loop k =
  if k = 0 then 0 else 
  let a = read_int () in
    let b = read_int () in
      let c = read_int () in
        let d = read_int () in
            Printf.printf "%s \n" (isRectangleIn a b c d)
            loop (k-1);;


let i = read_int ();;
let result = loop i;;
```

Compiler says that

```
This expression has type
         ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, 'a -> 'b -> 'c)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b -> 'c, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       Type 'a -> 'b -> 'c is not compatible with type unit
```

but I dont understand what i am doing wrong. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see an error displaying `CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt`, it means that a printf function is involved. Moreover, if there is a function type (here `'a -> 'b -> 'c`) in the first parameter of the format, the error is that printf have too many argument compared to the format string.

In your case, the format string is `"%s \n"`, which requires one argument, however you are using it with 3 arguments:

```
Printf.printf "%s \n" (isRectangleIn a b c d) loop (k-1)
```

(One can notice that there is as many supernumerary arguments in this function application and in the function type in the type error message.)

The root issue here is a missing `;` between the printf expression and `loop (k-1)`:

```
Printf.printf "%s \n" (isRectangleIn a b c d);
loop (k-1)
```

To avoid this kind of issue, it is generally advised to use ocp-indent (or ocamlformat) to indent code automatically and avoid deceitful indentation. For instance, ocp-indent  would have indented your code as

```
Printf.printf "%s \n" (isRectangleIn a b c d)
  loop (k-1);;
```

manisfesting the fact that `printf` and `loop` are not as the same level.